# Trying to append (>>) multiple commands to a file in one line

Tags: linux, ubuntu, append, command-line-interface

I'm trying to find a way to capture the stdout for two commands which are ran back to back in one line.

For example if I have a blank file named "practice.txt":

```
echo Hello World; pwd >> practice.txt
```

I want the file to now contain:

```
Hello World
/home/sean
```

I'm not sure if this is already a frequently asked question or not, but I couldn't find anyone else asking after a quick search. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to run it once, consider a subshell

```sh
( echo "Hello World" ; pwd ) >> practice.txt
```

If you expect to run the collection several times (perhaps declaring something useful in your shell's `.*rc` file), you could put both calls into a function

```sh
fn() {
    echo "Hello World"
    pwd
}
```

This can also be done on a single line

```sh
% fn() { echo "Hello World" ; pwd }
% fn >> practice.txt
% cat practice.txt
Hello World
/home/sean
```

Comment: I also get the same error using `fn() { echo "Hello World" ; pwd}
fn >> logs/trial1.txt`both of which are in scripts. It works from the cli.

Comment: hmmm - it's hard to understand without the newlines, but in the 3rd example `%` is indicating a shell prompt (zsh in my case). However, it could be that `#!/usr/bin/bash` does not exist and is falling back to another shell (such as `sh`) .. does [shellcheck](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck) have any insight?

Comment: I found the problem. In a bash script the "{}" need to be on separate lines. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @pink_floyd668 ahah / sorry! it's expecting a trailing `;` to end the statement: `fn() { echo test;}`